# onkeyup event is not working with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is the view code fragments for this issue

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group form-merchant">
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control inputs",placeholder:"Password" , required: true , id: 'password' , onchange: 'disableregisterbutton()'  %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group form-merchant">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control inputs",placeholder:"Confirm Password" , required: true , id: 'confirm_password' , onkeyup: 'disableregisterbutton()'  %>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">

  <%= f.submit "Register" ,class:"btn btn-primary btn-merchant-reg",style:"float:right;margin-right:-90px;height:50px;width:150px;", id: "register"  %>

</div>
```

The javascript code fragment is here

**

```html
<script>
    function disableregisterbutton() {
        var a = document.getElementById("confirm_password").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("password").value ;
        if (a == b){
            document.getElementById("register").disabled = false
        }else {
            document.getElementById("register").disabled = true
        }



    }
</script>
```

**

but in here the register button is not disabled when there is a password mismatch

[image]

Comment: are you using jquery ?

Comment: @gabbar javascript

Comment: Do you get any error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to by default disable the submit button and on change confirm password value it should be disable true or false accordingly.

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group form-merchant">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control inputs",placeholder:"Confirm Password" , required: true , id: 'confirm_password' , onkeyup: 'disableregisterbutton()'  %>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">

  <%= f.submit "Register" ,class:"btn btn-primary btn-merchant-reg",style:"float:right;margin-right:-90px;height:50px;width:150px;", id: "register", disabled: true%>

</div



<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableregisterbutton() {
        //var a = $('#confirm_password').val();
        //var b = $("#password").val();
        //for javascript
        var a = document.getElementById("confirm_password").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("password").value ;
        if (a == b){
            //$("#register").prop('disabled', false);
            document.getElementById("register").prop('disabled', false);
        }else {
            //("#register").prop('disabled', true);
              document.getElementById("register").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: $('#confirm_password').keyup(  function () {

            if ($('#confirm_password').val() === $('#password').val() ){
                $("#register").prop('disabled', false);

            }else {
                $("#register").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        })

Comment: when i am typing on the confirmation password field it doesnt give any console erroe

Comment: yeah it gives   new:1050 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).prop is not a function
    at disableregisterbutton (new:1050)

Comment: hmm use only one either jquery or javascript.

Comment: use setAttribute instead of prop.